# Can't edit drupal block

Tags: drupal, block, edit

I'm trying to add this block but can't see the content...

I have try to change the input type from filtered html to full and to php but still can't see the content to edit it...

Thank you

[See image](http://virbu.com/drupal-block.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to the original question

From the limited details you provided, it "appears" to me that what you are trying to say is something like this: "I want to edit the content of some block, but the block is not shown anywhere (and therefor I cannot edit it either)".

If I'm correctly interpreting your problem, then I'm about sure that you should navigate to `admin/structure/block` within your site. Then select the TAB (near the top) that corresponds to the Drupal "theme" that you are using. Probably the very first tab to the left is what you need to be looking at. Scroll down to the bottom of that page, towards the set of blocks below "Disabled". There you should then see the block listed that you are looking for. Edit the selection list to the right of it, and select a "region" like left column, 1st column, or whatever other region you want (just NOT disabled). And hit the "save" button near the bottom of that list. Then verify if the block starts to show up.

If this is NOT what you are looking for, then consider editing your question to better explain what your problem really is.

## Answer to the extra comment

The comment added to this answer seems to be a completely different question. This is what the coment looks like (slightly reformatted to enhance readability):

> ... I have a views that shows one post per category at [citybet.gr](http://citybet.gr) and need to remove the 2 last ones (**Μπόμπες** and **Γκολ - Γκολ**). This views is showing like a block but when I tried to edit this block I can't see the content to edit. I just can't find a way to remove the 2 last categories.

Some things to address this:

- this "block" (as you call it) is shown because you probably have nothing specified within "Site Information" (within configuration) as the relative path of your homepage. So therefor you use the default, which is relative path "Node", and which shows a list of "teasers" of nodes that have been marked as "promoted to the frontpage".
- if you do not want to include any of these teasers of specific nodes (like the 2 nodes you mentioned with **Μπόμπες** and **Γκολ - Γκολ**), then for each of these nodes you have to edit them and uncheck the flag that says "promoted" to frontpage. After you do so, those 2 specific nodes will no longer be shown in the list of teasers of nodes promoted to the front page.

Curious to hear if this somehow helps ...

PS: the layout of that ticker-bar near the top of your page is way to long (at the right), and causes a terrible display of your entire site on (at least) my mobile device ... you may want to work on that as well ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I have a views that shows one post per category at home page http://www.citybet.gr/ and need to remove the 2 last ones (Μπόμπες, Γκολ - Γκολ). This views is showing like a block but when i tried to edit this block i can't see the content to edit. I just can't find a way to remove the 2 last categories... Thank you